# Getting 'permission denied' error while accessing /root folder in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. How to resolve?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I can't access the /root folder. What should I do to gain access?

I tried `su - root` but it asked for a password which I don't have. I connected to this server using SSH private key.

I want to write something to the root folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query is related to `OCI Compute Instance` then please try the command `sudo su -` after you login to your compute instance using default `opc` user.

This works because of the entry in `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
[opc@ameen ~]$ pwd
/home/opc
[opc@ameen ~]$ ls
[opc@ameen ~]$ cd /root
-bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
[opc@ameen ~]$ sudo su -
[root@ameen ~]# cd /root
[root@ameen ~]# ls
[root@ameen ~]# logout
[opc@ameen ~]$
```